# How can I resolve the, "feed a value for placeholder tensor" error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm brand new to Tensorflow and while following through a book I have found that their sample data is too verbose for me to follow what Tensorflow is doing. That being the case I have made my own ultra small csv file instead. After working through several errors I am at the end of my script and can't seem to work through this final error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'y' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
>   [[Node: y = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Below is my code and below that I have included the output of the print statements. Can anyone help me understand this error. Also, I am aware that my mock data will not output any sensible model I just want to get it working first before switching to more complicated data. Thanks!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tarfile
import os

def load_data():
    return pd.read_csv("datasets/housing/mock.csv")

#load the data  
mockData = load_data()
print("mock data:")
print(mockData)

#add the bias
mockDataPlusBias = np.c_[np.ones((3,1)), mockData]
print("Mock data and bias:")
print(mockDataPlusBias)

#create placeholders
X = tf.constant(mockDataPlusBias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1), name="y")

#for use with matmul
XT = tf.transpose(X)
print("X:")
print(X)
print("XT:")
print(XT)
print("y:")
print(y)

theta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(XT, XT)), XT), y)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    theta_value = theta.eval()
    print(theta_value)
```

And lastly the print statements:

```
mock data:
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     4     5
2     7     8
Mock data and bias:
[[1. 1. 2.]
 [1. 4. 5.]
 [1. 7. 8.]]
X:
Tensor("X:0", shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
XT:
Tensor("transpose:0", shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
y:
Tensor("y:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are successfully declaring what the shape and type of 'y' is but not actually specifying any value for y. For placeholders, you also need to use **feed_dict** to set the value(s) for y during tf.Session run.

[See example here](https://learningtensorflow.com/lesson4/).

A useful starting point is the [official Tensorflow guides](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a little footwork to do with the syntax but that first link was helpful. I changed my 'y' placeholder to shape (None, 3) and my theta_value line became this instead: result = theta.eval(feed_dict={y: mockDataPlusBias}). Unfortunately I had to change my formula completely for theta because now I can't get matrix inverse to work but one issue down so I'll post on the next one in a different question. Thanks again!

Comment: Tensorflow syntax and structure is not the easiest for learning - if you have a choice, consider starting with Keras which has a simpler interface but compromises a bit on the ability to tweak some NN details